# How do I add a node between two other nodes in a HBox?

Tags: java, javafx, hbox

Consider the following code:

```
HBox hbox = new HBox();
Button button1 = new Button("A");
Button button2 = new Button("B");
hbox.getChildren().addAll(button1, button2);
```

If I wanted to add a node between the two current nodes, is there a way to do it without removing all the nodes first then re-adding them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since `getChildren()` returns an `ObservableList`, shouldnt you be able to use the `add(int index, E element)` to add the element at your desired index?

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't exactly sure where to start on the Java Docs to obtain my answer but your answer walked me right through it. I should be able to answer similar questions now, much appreciated.